# Ordering rows when they are not numeric

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, tidyr

using `df` below, I made a table with frequencies for each unit according to each combination of `group/year`.

After obtaining absolute and relative frequencies, I have pasted the values into just one column `Frequency`

Is there a way that I can after changing the table to have the units on the rows, have them ordered in descending order based on `n` of the `Total` group in 2016? I want my final output to not have rows with `n` and `prop`, only `Frequency`

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(sample(c('Controle','Tratado'),
                              10, replace = T),
                       sample(c(2012,2016), 10, T),
                       c('A','B','A','B','C','D','D','A','F','A')))

colnames(df) <- c('Group', 'Year', 'Unit')

table <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, Group) %>%
  count(Unit) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%                                               
              mutate(Group ="Total") %>%                         
              group_by(Year, Group) %>%                         
              count(Unit)) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n))

is.num <- sapply(table, is.numeric)
table[is.num] <- lapply(table[is.num], round, 4)
table <- table %>%
  mutate(Frequency = paste0(n,' (', 100*prop,'%)'))

table <- table %>%
  gather(type, measurement, -Year, -Group, -Unit) %>%
  unite(year_group, Year:Group, sep = ":") %>%
  spread(year_group, measurement)
```

Here is what I am expecting to generate:

```
 Unit      type 2012:Total 2012:Tratado 2016:Controle 2016:Total 2016:Tratado
1    A Frequency 2 (66.67%)   2 (66.67%)             - 2 (28.57%)     2 (100%)
2    D Frequency          -            -       2 (40%) 2 (28.57%)            -
3    B Frequency 1 (33.33%)   1 (33.33%)       1 (20%)  1 (14.29%)           -
4    C Frequency          -            -       1 (20%)  1 (14.29%)           -
5    F Frequency          -            -       1 (20%)  1 (14.29%)            -
```

Notice that the results are ordered according to column `2016:Total`

Comment: You've listed the output you're expecting it to generate, but can you list the output that your code *is* generating? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out a way myself, probably not the best one.

After running the code on the question, I have done the following:

```
table <- subset.data.frame(table, type == 'Frequency')

table <- table %>% 
  mutate(value = substr(Total_2016, 1, nchar(Total_2016) - 7 )) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  arrange(desc(value))
```